# UNIX: How to count the number of characters in a line, and find for any line that has the same number of characters?

Tags: unix, count, character, line

how would you count the number of total characters in a line, return the number, and then look for any other lines with a similar character count?

So, for example, the input:

```
this is a line
this is the second line
this is the third line
```

would return the output

```
14    1
23    1
22    1
```

where the first number is the number of characters in the first line, and the second number is the number of lines that that number of characters appear in.

Comment: It is possible, for example with `awk`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can do it without `awk` as well - just use a `while` loop to  read your file line by line, use `wc -w` to count the words on each line, then use `sort` and `uniq -c` to find the number of occurrences of each number.

Answer (score 0):

Since there was no attempt made to try and solve it yourself, I will give you some hints to make an attempt using `awk`:

#### Hint 1:

- `awk` has a global substitution function called `gsub` which returns number of substitutions made. It's construct is `gsub(regexp, replacement, target)`
- If you use `/./` in the regex, and keep `$0` as the target, it will substitute all characters of the line and return the number of substitutions made.
- Capture that return value and use that as a key to an array and increment the array to keep count.
- In the `END` block, using `for (key in array)` construct, print the `key` and `array[key]`.

#### Hint 2:

- You can use `length()` function which returns the length of the line and use that as a key to an array.
- Once your entire file has been read by `awk`, follow the last step of previous hint.